# Can I run a 100amp breaker off a 100amp subpanel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

There is a 100amp sub panel from my house to our shed currently, buried in conduit. I'm going to build a new workshop between the house and this shed that I ideally want to have 100amps available too. Instead of disrupting the current conduit run I was thinking of branching from the shed 100amp panel back to the shed which is about 10' away, so, dig the trench and just run the new conduit. Are there any issues with running 100 amp from this subpanel to another subpanel or should I just play it safe and do 80amps? Or, should I try to break the conduit in the middle and then branch from this to the shed?[image]

Edit: Adding a picture of the shed sub panel

[image]

Comment: 100A is the maximum _concurrent_ power that can run through the breaker before it things about tripping. The odds of you using that much power, all at once, either in the shed or the new shop, or both, are, most likely very, very small. However, you'll have to tell us what equipment you're planning on installing in the new shop and what's in the old shed in order for someone to help you with the load planning.

Comment: Splitting up the conduit opens a **huge** can of worms. Given the distances, running a new short conduit from shed to workshop makes sense. Code generally would allow that (assuming there aren't other issues already, as indicated in another question), so the *subpanel* will be the determining factor. Please upload pictures of the existing shed subpanel.

Comment: So many problems: Wires chopped that could/should have been removed; ground & neutral on same bar (always separate in subpanels); not clear (and based on other question, probably *not*) if there is an actual ground (as opposed to just using neutral as ground); there should be a disconnect for the building, but if the feed wires come straight from the main panel and go here to lugs then there is no building disconnect - can probably use a backfeed breaker instead of lugs to do that.

Comment: For the existing outbuilding, where is the disconnect switch?  (I mean you're legal right now, but if there isn't a separate disconnect switch, we'll need to do a trick so you can add a 7th breaker there.  It won't cost any extra.)

Comment: Can you post photos of the label on the inside of the shed panel's door? Also, how many square feet is the shed, are there any other loads of note to be concerned about in there, and what size are the wires feeding the shed panel?